# Yii facebook login issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii, oauth-2.0

I have created an facebook application in Yii and make user(s) login to my application using their facebook credentials .I'm using OAuth for facebook authentication and it's works fine on local server but doesn't work on [php AppFog server](http://www.appfog.com). Link to my application is http://nettantra-cvbuilder.aws.af.cm/ .
Can any body tell what will be the problem .

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the URLs in your Facebook App are incorrect. You need to replace those with the final ones in the App settings (at least 'Site URL' in 'Website with Facebook Login').